# No Icon came up next to the name on the UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiimageview

Sorry if this turned out to be a stupid question~

Here is my Code in the UITableViewController.m

---

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath     *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    // Configure the cell....

    cell.textLabel.text = [[[friendList friends] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] profileName];
    cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Zaka.jpg"];
    return cell;
}
```

---

The List of Names did popped up but there's no icon next to any of it.

Comment: Are you sure image is correctly added to project and check case sensitive name for it

Comment: Post an answer with a solution for others